# Can't find the cause of an Open GL ES error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm using Open GL ES 3.1 in my app and I'm facing a problem I haven't be able to fix so far.

When I try to create a 3D object, depending on where the constructor is called, either the object is correctly created (and can be displayed successfully) or the app crashes because shaders can't be created (call to `glCreateShader()` returns 0). This lets me say my shader codes are correct.

When I try to get information about the error with `glGetError()`, I receive `GL_NO_ERROR`, even when the returned shader is 0!

I have also added `setDebugFlags(DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS)` but it doesn't give me any clue.

I supposed the problem could be caused by concurrent access to the Open GL environment and I had my drawing and animating methods synchronized but it didn't help either.

According to this question [Compile GLSL shader asynchronously or in a different thread on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732228/compile-glsl-shader-asynchronously-or-in-a-different-thread-on-android), I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the impossibility to use the main Open GL environment in a separate thread. But I can't be sure of that because the code given uses class I can't find in the Open GL ES 3.1 library (`EGLContext2`, `eglCreateContext`, `eglCreatePbufferSurface`).

Does anyone know how I can access the Open GL ES environment from my second thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a second EGL context for the second thread, and place it inside the same share group as the the first context so they can share resources. You do this by providing the first context as the `share_context` parameter when calling `eglCreateContext()` for the second context.

> But I can't be sure of that because the code given uses class I can't find in the Open GL ES 3.1 library (`EGLContext2`, `eglCreateContext`, `eglCreatePbufferSurface`).

As the function prefix might give away, for context creation you need the EGL library not the GL library.

Comment: OK, I've found the `EGL`functions. In the answer from the question I mentionned above, the second context creation takes three undescribed parameters. I suppose `display` should be replaced by `EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay` and `EGLContext1` by `EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext`but what about `eglConfig`?

Comment: I have a config, which is a parameter of the `onSurfaceCreated`function, but it belongs to the `javax.microedition.khronos.egl`class and both `EGL14.eglCreateContext` and `EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface`functions need an `android.opengl.EGLConfig` object. Is there a way to convert one to the other?

Comment: Similar question, with sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985858/gles10-glgetintegerv-returns-0-in-lollipop-only